# RxSwift set observable value in another observable next , not working

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I am new to ios and rxswift. Trying create mvvm architecture for new app.

If I set observable isSuccess  value before calling appStartNetwork.fetchApp() I can observe value. But when I set isSuccess value in fetchApp() on next, Observer in viewcontroller cant be triggered

Whats wrong?

ViewModel

```
class SplashViewModel {
var isSuccess = PublishSubject<Bool>()
var isLoading = PublishSubject<Bool>()

private let bag = DisposeBag()
func fetchAppStart() {
    self.isLoading.onNext(true)

    let appStartNetwork=NetworkProvider.shared.makeAppStartNetwork()
    appStartNetwork.fetchApp().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] apiResult in
        switch apiResult{
        case let .success(response):
            //some codes
            self?.isLoading.onNext(false)
            self?.isSuccess.onNext(true)
            break
        case let .failure(errorContent):
            break
        }
        },onError:{ err in
            self.isLoading.onNext(false)
            self.isSuccess.onNext(false)
    }).disposed(by: bag)
}   }
```

View Controller

```
func getAppStart(){
    let splashVm=SplashViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    splashVm.isSuccess.subscribe(onNext: { (ok) in
        if(ok){
            print("splash success")
            self.navigateMain()
        }else{
            self.showAlert("splash fail")
        }

    },onError:{ err in
        self.showAlert(err.localizedDescription)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    splashVm.fetchAppStart()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, both created by the same programming error, a wrong management of the dispose bag lifecycles.

By creating your dispose bag within the scope of `getAppStart`, you are bounding its lifecycle to the function's life time. Meaning the dispose bag will dispose of its attached subscriptions when the function finishes.

Moving the creating of both `disposeBag` and `splashVm` to the view controller's scope (outside the function), should fix your issue.

```
let splashVm=SplashViewModel()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func getAppStart(){
    splashVm.isSuccess.subscribe(onNext: { (ok) in
        if(ok){
            print("splash success")
            self.navigateMain()
        }else{
            self.showAlert("splash fail")
        }

    },onError:{ err in
        self.showAlert(err.localizedDescription)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    splashVm.fetchAppStart()
 }
```